# Toggle using only css - select the next element that has a specific class

Tags: html, css, css-position

I need when the Trigger is clicked(checkbox checked) that the content(ul) to appear as a horizontal list, below the wrapper(red and blue colors).

Looks like the `+`(for next) doesn't work because even if is the next element, it is in a different parent.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 130px;
  background: red;
}

.lp {
  color: $white;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: blue;
}

.lp .toggle {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 20px;
}

.trigger { display:none;}

.content {
  display: none;
}
  
.trigger:checked + .content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="lp">
        <div class="toggle">
            <label for="menu-toggle">
                <span>Trigger</span>
            </label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="trigger" id="menu-toggle"/>
        </div>
    <ul class="content">
        <li><a href="#">First link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Third link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you alter the html-structure? If not then I'm afraid this needs javascript.

Comment: yes, but I need to obtain what I need(not just the triggered checkbox), but the content below the wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated. So I've made a quick demo. Hopefully this is enough to get you going :)

```css
.checkbox:not(checked) {
    display: none;
}

.checkbox:not(checked) ~ .content {
    display: none;
}
.checkbox:checked ~ .content {       
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="lp">
      <input type="checkbox" value="selected" id="1" class="checkbox"/>
      <label for="1" >Trigger</label>
    <ul class="content">
      <li><a href="#">First link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Third link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it can work, but I want to try something without javascript, since the using oif checkbox; I can add the trigger and content in the same div, but I don't know in this case how to push the ul below, and keep centered the trigger

Comment: Updated. I hope this is better.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do, with the posted code of yours, is to move the `input` so it becomes the previous sibling of the `ul`.

With that the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+` will work properly and toggle the *hidden menu*

Stack snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
}

section {
  position: relative;
}
  section .content {
    background: yellow;
    padding: 20px;
  }

.lp {
  color: $white;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: lightblue;
}

.lp .toggle {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 20px;
}
.lp .content {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(15px);
  padding-left: 18px;
  list-style: none;
}

.content, .trigger {
  display: none;
}

.trigger:checked+.content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="lp">
    <div class="toggle">
      <label for="menu-toggle">
                <span>Trigger</span>
            </label>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="trigger" id="menu-toggle" />
    <ul class="content">
      <li><a href="#">First link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Third link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

As mentioned in a comment, if you have content that is sibling of your `.wrapper` and also needs to be toggled, you can instead use the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) `~`.

For the `input` to be able to *"see"* e.g. both these elements, put it before the `.wrapper`.

Stack snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
}

section {
  position: relative;
}
  section .content {
    background: yellow;
    padding: 20px;
  }

.lp {
  color: $white;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: lightblue;
}

.lp .toggle {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 20px;
}
.lp .content {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(15px);
  padding-left: 18px;
  list-style: none;
}

.content, .trigger {
  display: none;
}

.trigger:checked ~ .wrapper .content,
.trigger:checked ~ section .content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="trigger" id="menu-toggle" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="lp">
    <div class="toggle">
      <label for="menu-toggle">
                <span>Trigger</span>
            </label>
    </div>
    <ul class="content">
      <li><a href="#">First link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Third link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<section>
  <div class="content">
    Some other dummy text that will show...
  </div>
</section>
```